# In python what is difference between assign a variable in single line and assigning a variable in multiple lines

Tags: python

I have written a script for Fibonacci series with single line variable assignment and multiple line variable assignment. I got two different results

Multiple lines:

```
class fibonacci:
    def fib(self,num):
      result = []
      a = 0
      b = 1
      while a < num:
          result.append(a)
          a = b
          b =  a + b
      return result

instance = fibonacci()
new_inst = instance.fib(100)
print new_inst
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

Order Changed:

```
class fibonacci:
    def fib(self,num):
      result = []
      b = 1
      a = 0
      while a < num:
          result.append(a)
          b = a + b
          a = b
      return result

instance = fibonacci()
new_inst = instance.fib(100)
print new_inst
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

Single line:

```
class fibonacci:
    def fib(self,num):
      result = []
      a,b = 0,1
      while a < num:
          result.append(a)
          a,b = b, a + b
      return result

instance = fibonacci()
new_inst = instance.fib(100)
print new_inst
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is the order of evaluation. When you assign

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

The right-hand expressions are evaluated fully before assignment to the left hand side, so the order of evaluation is:

```
foo = a + b
bar = a
b = foo
a = bar
```

This is different to the order of evaluation in your first example, which is:

```
 a = b
 b =  a + b
```

Hence your two examples generate different results.

To work around your issue, I would probably use:

```
c = a
a = b
b = a + c
```

This generates the correct output as desired.

Comment: `class fibonacci:
    def fib(self,num):
      result = []
      a,b = 0,1
      while a < num:
          result.append(a)
          b = a + b
          a = b
      return result

instance = fibonacci()
new_inst = instance.fib(100)
print new_inst` but still i got same output: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

Comment: I have changed the order but still I got the two different outputs

Comment: but why should I use one more variable?

Comment: You don't need to. Your 2nd example is correct. However, for clarity (and your understanding), my solution might be easier.